# Visual studio 2017 (15.4.1) typescript highlight

Tags: visual-studio, resharper

I use resharper in my VS studio 2017, after updating VS to 15.4.1 typescript highlight code dissaperd, maybe some of you have a solution?

Because I tried to repair VS, than clean resharper to default settings

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I added back highlight with 
[image]

( https://developercommunity.visualstudio.com/content/problem/39166/javascript-certain-keywords-are-not-highlighted-in.html )